# Flutter Firestore await .getDocuments took 30 mins

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I call this query

```
    print("JJJason Button querying Firestore min data");
    var querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('devices')
        .document(widget.deviceId)
        .collection('min')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments();

    print("JJJason Button Firestore query requested");
    var requestedSampleNum = 0;
    if ((querySnapshot != null) && (querySnapshot.documents != null) && (querySnapshot.documents.length > 0)) {
      var document = querySnapshot.documents.first;
      requestedSampleNum = int.parse(document.documentID);
      requestedSampleNum ~/= 60;
      requestedSampleNum += 1;
      print("JJJason Button requestedSampleNum from Firestore is $requestedSampleNum");
    } else {
      print("JJJason Button requestedSampleNum not found in Firestore so it is $requestedSampleNum");
    }
```

The database does not have a collection called "min" (yet), so I would expect this to return almost immediately, however it actually took ~30 mins. From 9:50 until 10:19

```
2020-09-30 09:50:33.805 17068-17108/com.abcabc.abccccc I/flutter: JJJason Button pressed
2020-09-30 09:50:33.806 17068-17108/com.abcabc.abccccc I/flutter: JJJason Button querying Firestore min data
2020-09-30 10:19:42.533 17068-17108/com.abcabc.abccccc I/flutter: JJJason Button Firestore query requested
2020-09-30 10:19:42.534 17068-17108/com.abcabc.abccccc I/flutter: JJJason Button requestedSampleNum not found in Firestore so it is 0
```

It seems like there's an in-built 30 minute timeout.
Should I add .timeout(Duration(seconds:magicNumberOfSeconds)) to each firestore call?

Any help or advice is gratefully received.

-Jason

edit: adding requested screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you please share what are you trying to achieve and what's the business logic along with screenshots of firestore database?

Comment: @HaroonAshrafAwan I've added a screenshot.

Comment: I'm trying to read a collection of documents from the database to determine what records to request from a bluetooth device. The collection may already exist but in this case it does not exist. Yesterday I deleted the collection via the firestore dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some dummy data to the min collection and seeing what happens then? That would give you a better idea of what is going on (is it a network problem, Firebase problem etc)

Comment: Hi, The collection has had data in the past, which it normally retrieves quickly. I've been adding more features so to test something I deleted this collection yesterday.